# Disable directory indexing on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'd like to disable directory indexing on Apache.

This is my .htaccess file in full. But as soon as I uncomment `Options -Indexes` the server falls over.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#Options –Indexes

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# Turn on the Expires engine
  ExpiresActive On

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 hour"

# Media: images
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: In what manner does the server fall over - what error messages to you see ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else hits the same problem, the problem was that I'd *copied and pasted* in the line:

```
Options –Indexes
```

And Apache couldn't cope with the encoding of the hyphen!

Answer (score 2):

Probably your Apache has been configured in `httpd.conf` with `AllowOverride` set to such values it does not allow you to tune any options in .htaccess.

Do you have access to `httpd.conf` or Apache error log?